# How do I import aliases from a file?

Tags: linux, terminal, alias

I'm using a couple of aliases for Laravel artisan commands. I'm trying to store those aliases in a file for future use. Is there any way to import aliases from a file to Gnu/Linux terminal?. So I can store the aliases I'm using every day in a file and import them anytime I want on different computers.

Comment: Share the file format?

Answer (score 2):

That's easy enough:

If you are using `bash`, keep a snippet like this one...

```bash
if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ]; then
   source "$HOME/.bash_aliases"
fi
```

for every file you want to import in your `~/.bashrc`.
You could write `.` instead of `source`, but personally I like the long form better.